# Tcl proc to output a list or array

Tags: arrays, list, tcl, proc

I am new to Tcl arrays. My question is as follows.

I have a rectangle box with two rows R1 and R2. Each of these rows has 8 different values.
I want to return these 16 values (x and y coordinates) either in a text file or as an list output from a proc. I read some earlier posts about Tcl proc cannot output an array unless we use dict.
So, I will try to draw a picture so u can understand my question better.

```
R1  x1y1    x2y2        ... x8,y8
R2  x9,y9       ...     x16, y16
```

Expected output when I run the proc either on command prompt or in a file with dummy values as an example

```
$>    (1,2)  (2,3) (3,4) ....... (7,8)
      (9,10) (10,11) ......... (15,16)
```

So this is what I tried and I am getting the results that I need. But this is hardcoded for two rows. I want to make it able to detect how many rows are there and then accordingly output the number of rows.

```
proc getPointList {rect_boundary rowOffset colOffset rowIncr colIncr } {
 set cordlist $rect_boundary

 set xl  [lindex $cordlist 0]
 set yl  [lindex $cordlist 1]
 set xh  [lindex $cordlist 2]      
 set yh  [lindex $cordlist 3]

 set list "" ;

 for {set y [expr {$yh - $colOffset}]} {$y >= [expr {$yl + $colOffset}]} { incr y $colIncr } {

    for {set x [expr {$xl + $rowOffset}]} {$x <= [expr {$xh - $rowOffset}]} { incr x $rowIncr } {

            set list "$list $x $y" ;
            puts "Value of x is: $x"; puts "\t Value of y is: $y" ;  
        } 
 }
return $list  
}

set rect_boundary {10 15 100 40}     # xl yl xh yh
set rowOffset 5
set colOffset 5
set rowIncr 10
set colIncr 15
```

Some Logic I need to implement in this code based on yh-yl and xh-xl to calculate height and width of rectangle and accordingly output rows

Command to call the proc

```
$> getPointList $rect_boundary $rowOffset $colOffset $rowIncr $colIncr
```

Just for your understanding there are eight x,y points inside the rectangle on a particular row.
x offset is the first x point on a row from the left or roght boundary, thereafter all the points are separated by an increment value which I call rowIncr. Same holds true for column.

Expected output :  This is what the above code does but it is hardcoded for two rows. I want to increase and implement the logic if the rows and column are variable.

```
$>  R1:  (15 40) (25 40) (35 40) (45 40) (55 40) (65 40) (75 40) (85 40) (95 40)
    R2:  (15 15) (25 15) (35 15) (45 15) (55 15) (65 15) (75 15) (85 15) (95 15)
```

Rectangle Image for better clarity as this thing wont let me update pictures

```
__________________________________________________________________________ (100,40)
|                       |- 5                                              |
|   .          .        .       .        .       .        .        .      |
|                               |- 15                                     |
|-5-.          . --10---.       .        .       .        .        .      |
|                                                                         |
|_________________________________________________________________________|
(10,15)
```

For Jerry:

```
Case1  rowIncr 10 colIncr 20
__________________________________________________________________________ (80,40)
|                       |- 5                                              |
|   .          .        .       .        .       .        .        .      |
|                               |- 20                                     |
|-5-.          . --10---.       .        .       .        .        .      |
|                                                                         |
|_________________________________________________________________________|
(10,10)

Case2   rowIncr 20 colIncr 35
_________________________________________________ (100,70)
|                       |- 5                     |
|   .          .        .       .        .       |
|                               |- 35            |
|-5-.          . --20---.       .        .       |
|              |                         |-5     |
|________________________________________________|
(10,25)
```

and so on ...

Comment: I understand that you want to extract the coordinates from the rectangle? Are the coordinates separated by a tab character and each x and y coordinate separated by comma?

Comment: Hi Jerry:  I only need the xy coordinates from inside the rectangle. I With or without comma separated value is not a question. Once I am able to do that I can use split to spearate the xy values and remove the comma too. Comma used in my question is an example, if it's not there then better.

Comment: Hi, could you also put a sample input with all the numbers and how you're calling the procedure? I'm having trouble understanding how is your actual input and required output with this proc... :(

Comment: We would like to help, so please help us by showing us what the input and expected output looks like, how you read the input, pass it to your function. You stated your input looks like 8 numbers per row, but your proc only takes in 5--the first is a list of 4--very confusing.

Comment: Hai Vu and Jerry: proc takes arguments, i will put in my question how to call the proc and sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I think I now understand what you were trying to do, and I think that your proc would have worked for any number of rows after some fixing:

```
set output [open "output.txt" w]

proc getPointList {rect_boundary rowOffset colOffset plist} {
    global output

    set cordlist $rect_boundary
    set xl  [lindex $cordlist 0]
    set yl  [lindex $cordlist 1]
    set xh  [lindex $cordlist 2]      
    set yh  [lindex $cordlist 3]

    set xpoints [llength [lindex $plist 0]]
    set ypoints [llength $plist]
    set rowIncr [expr {($xh-$xl-2*$rowOffset)/($xpoints-1)}]
    set colIncr [expr {($yh-$yl-2*$colOffset)/($ypoints-1)}]

    set count 0
    set list ""

    for {set y [expr {$yh - $colOffset}]} {$y >= [expr {$yl + $colOffset}]} {incr y -$colIncr} {

        for {set x [expr {$xl + $rowOffset}]} {$x <= [expr {$xh - $rowOffset}]} {incr x $rowIncr} {
            lappend list "($x,$y)"
        }
        incr count
        puts $output "R$count: [join $list " "]"
        set list ""
    }
}

set plist {{A B C D E} {A B C D E} {A B C D E} {A B C D E} {A B C D E}}
set rect_boundary {0 0 100 100}
set rowOffset 0
set colOffset 0

getPointList $rect_boundary $rowOffset $colOffset $plist

close $output
```

I changed the `colIncr` to put more rows.

In the first loop, I used `incr y -$colIncr` because this is actually a decrement if you start with the higher `y` coordinate.

I also changed the output structure to match the one you were looking for. The above snippet returns the coordinates:

```
R1: (0,100) (25,100) (50,100) (75,100) (100,100) 
R2: (0,75) (25,75) (50,75) (75,75) (100,75) 
R3: (0,50) (25,50) (50,50) (75,50) (100,50) 
R4: (0,25) (25,25) (50,25) (75,25) (100,25) 
R5: (0,0) (25,0) (50,0) (75,0) (100,0)
```

EDIT: Added variable offsets, blank final row and variable columns per row.

```
proc getPointList {rect_boundary uRowOffset lRowOffset uColOffset lColOffset plist} {
    set cordlist $rect_boundary
    set xl  [lindex $cordlist 0]
    set yl  [lindex $cordlist 1]
    set xh  [lindex $cordlist 2]      
    set yh  [lindex $cordlist 3]

    set xpoints 0
    foreach r $plist {
        if {[llength $r] > $xpoints} {set xpoints [llength $r]}
    }

    set ypoints [llength $plist]
    set rowIncr [expr {($xh-$xl-$lRowOffset-$uRowOffset)/($xpoints-1)}]
    set colIncr [expr {($yh-$yl-$lColOffset-$uColOffset)/$ypoints}]

    set count 0
    set list ""

    for {set y [expr {$yh - $uColOffset}]} {$y >= [expr {$yl + $lColOffset}]} {incr y -$colIncr} {
        set x [expr {$xl + $lRowOffset}]
        foreach n [lindex $plist $count] {
            lappend list $x $y
            incr x $rowIncr
        }
        incr count
        if {$count == $ypoints} {return $list}
    }
}

set plist {{A B C D X} {E F G H} {I K L} {M N}}
set qlist 1
foreach n $plist {
    set pattern$plist $n
    incr qlist
}

set rect_boundary {0 0 100 100}
set upperRowOffset 0
set lowerRowOffset 0
set upperColOffset 0
set lowerColOffset 0

set pointList [getPointList $rect_boundary $upperRowOffset $lowerRowOffset $upperColOffset $lowerColOffset $plist]

set count 1
foreach sub_list $plist {
    foreach n $sub_list {
        set pattern$count $n
        incr count
    }
}

set count 1
foreach {a b} $pointList {
    set text "pattern$count"
    puts "command -point $a,$b -text [set $text]"
    incr count 
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jerry !! Appreciate it. I normally put the - sign to account for the decrement when specifying the "set colIncr -5" I just forgot to mention in the problem statement snippet but ya your right. Let me try this code and see how it works.

Comment: One more thing Jerry: What should I do if my rowIncr and colIncr are changing dynamically on a case to case basis. ??

Comment: @user2643899 That shouldn't be a problem. Just make sure that the updated `colIncr` and `rowIncr` are being passed to the `proc`.

Comment: @user2643899 Or do you mean that they change for the same rectangle? (As in first row 5, then 10, then 5, etc and similarly for columns)

Comment: Jerry: Yes, I know I can pass updated the one to the proc, I meant dynamically changing as per your comment above.  Like ne rectangle with rowIncr and Column Incr of let say 10 for example and second rectangle with RowIncr and ColIncr of 15 and 20. 3rd rectangle of rowIncr 35 and ColIncr 68  .....so on and so forth

Comment: @user2643899 I'm not sure what you mean exactly, but if I got it right, you can create a proc to create several rectangles, which will call `getPointList` for each rectangle with the specified values. If you can give an example of how someone would go using this, it might make things clearer.

Comment: Jerry: I dont want to create several rectangles. As a matter of fact several rectables would be given to me as input on which I Intend to run my getPointList function. There are no specified values for rowIncr and ColIncr , I am calculating them based on the different size rectangles. The real question is how to ask Tcl code to calculate those values which change based on different width and height rectanlge boundary. I can provide more examples if it is not clear.

Comment: @user2643899 Okay, I understand that you are given the rectangle boundaries, right? Also, if you are not given the `rowIncr` or `colIncr`, I'm assuming that you are given the number of rows and columns, right? Also, some more examples would be welcome if I what I said in this comment are way off your point!

Comment: Jerry: Number of Rows, I am calculating from something and storing it into a variable. For example    set row_list {{1 2 3}{13 14 15}{20 21 22}}. Now, set numberof_rows [llength $row_list]  This returns 3. Column is automatically calculated from these if I split the above list into 3 rows then I have the number of columns I need (in this case : 3)   Only other thing apart from this is the rectangle boundary. I will add more details for you in my question original above

Comment: Please come to the Tcl rectangles chat room whenever you get a chance or send me a ping, I will be periodically checking it and we can then sync up accordingly

Comment: I have enabled desktop notification, can you please meet me at chat room

Comment: Because of you changing room permission am typing messages but it is not allowing me to post messages its saying rety/cancel

Comment: can you please come to the chat room

Comment: @user2643899 Hi! Sorry, I voluntarily cut off everything with the internet when my exams started :( I just saw your message and am more available as from today.

Comment: Hey no problem man I really needed your help but it is now taken cared of. How were your exams ? (chat room is frozen)

Comment: @user2643899 Weren't too bad, but I'll have to wait for the results. I made [another one](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46067/tcl-rectangles).

Answer (score 0):

It is up to you how to organize the nested lists. In simplest form, return a single list:

```
set result {x1 y1 x2 y2 ... x16 y16}
```

Or, you can have a list of two rows:

```
set result {
    {x1 y1 x2 y2 ... x8 y8}
    {x9 y9 x10 y10 ... x16 y16}
}
```

Or, more complex: each pair is a sub-list:

```
set result {
    { {x1 y1} {x2 y2} ... }
    { {x9 y9} {x10 y10} ... }
}
```

I don't think you want to use array in this case. FYI, an "array" in TCL is equivalent to a *hash* in other languages.

Comment: Hi Hai Vu: You just hardcoded the values as a list and anyone can use a puts or return after that. Actually, that is not what i want. But thanks for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Well, with Tcl 8.6

```
proc parsedata {input} {
    lmap a [split $input \n] {
        lmap b [split $b \t] {
           regexp {x(\d+),?\s*y(\d+)} $b -> c d
           list $c $d
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can process the data, for example:

```
foreach line [parsedata $input] {
    puts [lmap pair $line {
        expr {"([lindex $line 0],[linedex $line 1])"}
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Johannes, thanks for the code snippet. However, this will help me parse the code. I am not using Tcl 8.6 so it won't work for me anyways.